# how get belongsToMany's joinData?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

\src\Model\Entity\Item.php (line 42)

```
[
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Special) {

    'id' => (int) 1,
    'tag_cx' => (int) 1,
    'stock' => (int) 0,
    'status' => (int) 1,
    '_joinData' => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

        'special_id' => (int) 1,
        'id' => (int) 24,
        'item_id' => (int) 10,
        'discount' => (float) 7,
    },
    '[new]' => false,
}
]
```

How can I get `joinData`?

I can't use `$data[0]->_joinData`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$joinData = $data[0]->get('_joinData');
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
special->_joinData->special_id;
```

do that for other variables under `_joinData`.